# Running integration tests on the actual server using command line task in Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, xunit

I have a unique case where I need to run the integration tests on the same server that the API has been deployed to. In our current pipeline, we build the API and then deploy it to the alpha test server. What I want to achieve is adding another step after the deployment that will build and deploy the xunit test project and run it on the same server then get the results of the test back and if any of the tests fail I want to revert the deployment. I know that I can run the tests from the command line in windows, but first I basically need the entire bin folder to be created/build and put on the server. I know it's not the usual way to be doing integration tests in azure pipelines but that's a requirement for our project. We are not going to use Docker containers for a while. We use the new YAML pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly straightforward. In your pipeline, just add a task (after the deployment task) to run the tests! The build artifact will already be present with all the integration test code, so you just call the test runner in much the same way as you would when running them locally.